# Can I use two print heads to print mixed material based on own DIW extruder?

Tags: multi-material, hyrel

I want to use two SDS 5 (DIW) print heads on our Hyrel 3D printer to print one part with two different materials (not use the mixing component supplied by Hyrel company, because we want to DIY the printing nozzle). During the printing process, sometimes only one print head works, sometimes I need two print heads to work together.

I have thought of possible printing methods, but also have some drawbacks: Uses one print head as master, and another printing head clones the master head, but, using this method, we cannot control the mixed ratio of printing material during the printing process, the mixing ration is fixed during the printing process.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've answered Jingcheng already, as he also emailed us with this question.

For posterity, I summarize the answer below. I work for Hyrel 3D.

---

With two separate extruders, you can alternate between, for example, T0 and T2. When the head offset from T0 to T2 is stored on head T2, this provides for tool changes without editing any position or flow data.

For gcode details, please see https://hyrel3d.com/wiki/index.php/Gcode

---

Note, this is not specific to DIW (Direct Ink Writing), aka Robocasting. The user just happened to be doing DIW in this case. Tool changes are the same (on Hyrel equipment) for all material deposition methods.

Comment: For those of us new to 3D printing, what's a "DIW"  extruder?

Comment: Direct Ink Writing - printing with liquids or gels, usually at room temperature. Also called Robocasting. Thanks, I'll edit this.